# How to automatically inherit mixin generic type in self-types?

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, self-type

How do I inherit generic type from parent mixin type? For example I have a trait `Foo` with one generic type `A`:

```scala
trait Foo[A] {
  def value: A
}
```

I have a class `User` that uses `Foo[String]`, like:

```scala
class User extends Foo[String] {
  override def value: String = ???
}
```

Everything works fine. Now, I want to add a trait `Bar[A]` with self-type of `Foo[A]`.

```scala
trait Bar[A] { self: Foo[A] =>
  def anotherValue: A
}
```

If I want to use `Bar` in `User`, I'll need to do:

```scala
class User extends Foo[String] with Bar[String] {
  override def value: String = ???
  override def anotherValue: String = ???
}
```

Is there anyway that I can simplify `User` to this? (`Bar` automatically infers type from corresponding `Foo`.)

```scala
class User extends Foo[String] with Bar
```

Comment: Why do you need this? `extends Foo[String] with Bar` is not much shorter than `extends Foo[String] with Bar[String]`.

Comment: It becomes quite long if it is not `String`. Besides, I think the type `A` of `Bar` should be quite obvious that the compiler should be able to infer it.

Comment: Why not to define shorter type alias? `type A = SomethingLongerThanString`.

Comment: *should be quite obvious that the compiler should be able to infer it* It's not about inference, it's about syntax. If you have `Bar[A]` then `extends Bar` is illegal.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was thinking if there was maybe a way to use something else e.g. evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define intermediate trait

```
trait UserLike[A] extends Foo[A] with Bar[A]

class User extends UserLike[String] {
  override def value: String = ???
  override def anotherValue: String = ???
}
```

---

You can define a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) but this would be an overkill

```
@extendsBar
class User extends Foo[String] {
  override def value: String = ???
  override def anotherValue: String = ???
}

//scalac: {
//  class User extends Foo[String] with Bar[String] {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    override def value: String = $qmark$qmark$qmark;
//    override def anotherValue: String = $qmark$qmark$qmark
//  };
//  ()
//}

import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class extendsBar extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ExtendsBarMacro.impl
}

object ExtendsBarMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val fooArg = parents.collectFirst {
          case tq"Foo[$t]" => t
        }.getOrElse(c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "class must extend Foo"))
        val parents1 = parents :+ tq"Bar[$fooArg]"
        q"""
           $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents1 { $self => ..$stats }
           ..$tail
        """
      case _ =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "annottee must be a class")
    }
  }
}
```

---

This would be more flexible if `A` were a type member rather than type parameter

```
trait Foo {
  type A
  def value: A
}

trait Bar { self: Foo =>
  def anotherValue: A
}

class User extends Foo with Bar {
  override type A = String
  override def value: String = ???
  override def anotherValue: String = ???
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I also kinda thought of that, but it becomes a pain if you have multiple `Bar` mixins and all of their combinations. (Think `Bar1`, `Bar2`, `Bar3`; you'll have 7 different combinations and consequently 7 intermediate traits.) Is there a way to do this without an intermediate trait? (e.g. maybe using evidences?)

Comment: @krismath You can define a macro annotation. See update. But this would be an overkill.

Comment: @krismath *maybe using evidences* You will not make a class extend something using evidences. Are evidences enough for you? They are weaker than inheritance.

Comment: @krismath This would be more flexible if `A` were a type member. See update. By the way, why can't you make `Bar` extend `Foo` rather than use self-types.

Comment: I recall that I needed all the `Bar`s to share the same `Foo.value` (arguably the design can be improved, but we're digressing from the original question). Accepted the answer since it seems like this is the best I could get.